# TOAD SQL CASE Statement

Tags: sql, select, case, toad

I'm attempting to do what I consider a rather complicated case statement. What I want to achieve is this:

When DATE+365 is less than OTHERDATE AND it is equal to YETANOTHER DATE THEN 'Correct'

Right now my code looks like this:

```
(CASE WHEN ((X2.TERMDATE + 365) < X1.LASTHIRE) IS (X1.ORIGINALHIRE) THEN 'Correct' 

WHEN ((X2.TERMDATE + 365) < X1.LASTHIRE) IS (X3.LASTHIRE) THEN 'Correct' 

WHEN ((X2.TERMDATE + 365) > X1.LASTHIRE) IS (X1.LASTHIRE) THEN 'Correct' 

ELSE 'ERROR' END)
```

Is this possible? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think the problem is with these parts:

```
IS (X1.ORIGINALHIRE)
```

You probably have to replace it with this sort of thing

```
and something = x1.originalhire
```

Comment: Changing is to = still doesn't work.  I get the error 'missing a key word'.

Comment: @user1475816 Just changing IS to = isn't enough. Try changing `IS (X1.ORIGINALHIRE)` to `AND (X2.TERMDATE + 365) = X1.ORIGINALHIRE`, and changing the other lines similarly.

Comment: That solved the issue (with some additional tweaking) - thanks!